# JQuery JS Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

So, I have this issue that has been bugging me and I just can't seem to fix it. The error that comes up is this:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"type":"header","subtype":"h1","label":"Another test form"},{"type":"checkbox-group","label":"Checkbox Group","name":"checkbox-group-1497353080484","values":[{"label":"Option 1","value":"option-1","selected":true}]},{"type":"header","subtype":"h1","label":"Header"},{"type":"number","label":"Number","className":"form-control","name":"number-1497353081884"},{"type":"text","label":"Text Field","className":"form-control","name":"text-1497353083345","subtype":"text"}]

I have managed to track down the line of code that is causing this issue, which is this:

```
        forms = $(document.getElementById('formData').getAttribute("value")),
```

Now, I have no idea why this is causing this issue. The content coming in is correct. This is all being done within a JQuery function, in fact the whole JQuery function looks like this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $fbEditor = $(document.getElementById('fb-editor')),
  $formContainer = $(document.getElementById('fb-rendered-form')),
  forms = $(document.getElementById('formData').getAttribute("value")),
  fbOptions = {
   formData: forms,
   dataType: 'json',
   onSave: function(){
    $fbEditor.toggle();
    $formContainer.toggle();
    $('form', $formContainer).formRender({
     formData: formBuilder.formData
    });
   }
  },
  formBuilder = $fbEditor.formBuilder(fbOptions);
  
  $('.edit-form', $formContainer).click(function() {
   $fbEditor.toggle();
   $formContainer.toggle();
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So, I am not that experienced with JavaScript, JQuery or any of the rest of this. So it could very well be a simple issue but I cannot currently figure out what it is. Can somebody else tell me where I have gone wrong and possibly how to fix it?

Comment: what does this return when u `document.getElementById('formData')` and `document.getElementById('formData').getAttribute("value")` in ur console?

Comment: From the error it appears that the issue is because you're attempting to create a jQuery object from a JSON string. I'm not even sure what you're trying to achieve with that logic.

Comment: `getAttribute` returns a string. jQuery tries to parse that as either a selector or a HTML string, which fails. Why are you trying to wrap it in jQuery at all?

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. The question has now been answered, it was the $() that was causing the issue. So, parsing it as a Jquery was the issue, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forms = $(document.getElementById('formData').getAttribute("value")),`

Try removing the $() in the code above. As per poohitan, its a selector but it doesn't appear to be doing anything at all.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you soo much Ugotchi!

Answer (score 1):

From the error I guess `document.getElementById('formData').getAttribute("value")` is a JSON string.

You have wrapped it into jQuery object constructor `$(...)`, and it fails because jQuery expectes the parameter to be a selector (like `.classname`), DOM element, or another jQuery element.